# Moving files with shutil.move

Tags: python, file, shutil

i want to move files from a folder to antother.
I found out there is a function in the shutil module called

```
shutil.move(src,dest)
```

But i cant get it to work it always says that the files dont exist. Heres my Code:

```
source = 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Test1'
dest1 = 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Test2'

files = os.listdir(source)

for f in files:
    if (f.startswith("Test")):
        shutil.move(f, dest1)
```

The folders and files all exist.

Error:

> IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Test1.csv'

Anyone knows how to fix?

Comment: `os.listdir` `return`s the basepathname not the full path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`listdir` will just give you the filenames inside the directory, not the fully qualified names.
You can join them back together:

```
for f in files:
    if f.startswith("Test"):
        shutil.move(os.path.join(source, f), dest1)
```

Comment: Thanks alot! Works exactly like intended!